# CMD 2 keyboard shortcut no longer working

Tags: keyboard

Since Wednesday I can no longer use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> as shortcut in any application on my MacBook Pro. I've quadruple checked Keyboard Shortcuts in Settings and I have nothing there. <kbd>⌘</kbd> and any other key works fine.

Today I discovered that with an external keyboard attached, I can use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> by using the 2 key on the number pad, but not the 2 in the number row.

Ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that there is another menu item that has that shortcut? Or even another app that runs in the background and has something set to that shortcut?

Comment: The View menu flashes briefly when I press CMD 2 which is a common shortcut that I use in several apps.  I've checked every application I have running and looked at the global shortcuts but can't see anything else that would interfere.

Answer (score 1):

One common cause of a single key combo not working is that it gets set as the trigger for Text to speech or for Speech Recognition.  Double check system preferences/speech

Answer (score 0):

Log out, and then log in while holding down the `shift` key to keep any apps from launching, and see if that helps.

Or enable the Guest Account, log in there, and see if it still happens.

Not sure what might have happened, but this might at least help you rule out a few more possibilities.

Comment: Tried logging in with Shift key down and still no joy.  Another clue however - in Outlook, CMD 1, 2, 3 switches between email, calendar, and contacts respectively.  If I press and hold CMD, I can switch between 1 and 3 all night.  As soon as I use CMD 2 however, none of the combinations work until I release and press CMD again.

Comment: Try it with an external keyboard.